# * vs & Arduino Class

Tags: c++, pointers, arduino, pass-by-reference

Probably these kind of questions have been asked quite a few times and I also read a few blogs about pointers and references in C++. I have limited experience to C++. However, I was going through the following code from Arduino's PID library and I couldn't understand that during object instantiation the **"&"** is used which looks to me like pass by reference. But why is the Class using **"*"**?

```
**************** Class instantiation ******************

PID myPID(&Input, &Output, &Setpoint, Kp, Ki, Kd, DIRECT);    

**************** Code for class definition ******************

PID(double*, double*, double*, Input, Output,double, double, double, int, int);
```

Comment: It's important to understand that many symbols can mean different things in c++, depending on where they are used. Here, `&` is the address-of operator and produces a pointer to the operand. It is unrelated to references, except that references happen to use the same symbol.

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)  This will really help you to understand pointer and reference syntax.

Comment: `&variable` obtains it's pointer. `type*` declare a pointer to `type`. `type&` declares a reference to `type`. `*pointer` obtain the value of the variable it points to.

Comment: So &Input is a pointer in this case and * is giving the value stored at Input location? Do I understand it correctly? @NathanOliver Thanks you for the book.

Answer (score 1):

In this case & is the address-of operator.

The PID constructor's parameter list contains several pointers. `&Input` returns the address of `Input`. What do pointers store? Addresses!

For more info on the address-of operator & read:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access

> 1) &expr
>
> ...
>
> 1) If the operand is an lvalue expression of some object or function
>   type T, operator& creates and returns a prvalue of type T*, with the
>   same cv qualification, that is pointing to the object or function
>   designated by the operand....